# How to create a popup window in grails using jquery

Tags: jquery, grails

I install grails plugin compile ":javascript-url-mappings:0.1.1"
And then i  use this

```
 $('.general_cell').click(function(){
       var link ="${g.createLink(controller: 'registrationController', action: 'testAction')}";
       window.open(link, '', 'width=200,height=100');
   });
```

but i didn't get correct solution.It seems createLink create wrong pattern.Can anyone suggest me some good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use lowercase controller names without the added `Controller`, e.g. `controller: 'registration'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can go for modal in jQuery, or make an ajax call for some div, that will open as popup